# retrieving data from multidimensional array with php

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

i have a two dimensional array, and i want to retrieve its value in to separate variables. 
i'm using these codes, but it gives me a error saying

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in

this is the code i'm using to assign values to a multidimensional session.

```
if(isset($_POST['adnother'])) {
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $billnmbr = $_POST['billnmbr'];
  $itemcode = $_POST['itemcode'];
  $itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
  $exdate = $_POST['exdate'];   
  $eachprice = $_POST['eachprice']; 
  $itmtotal = $_POST['itmtotal'];
  $wasFound=false;
  $i=0; 
 //if the bill session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if(!isset($_SESSION["bill_array"]) || count($_SESSION["bill_array"]) < 1 ) {
        // Run if the bill is empty or not set
        $_SESSION["bill_array"]= array(1 => array("date"=> $date, "billnmbr"=> $billnmbr, "itemcode"=> $itemcode, "itemname"=> $itemname, "exdate"=> $exdate, "eachprice"=> $eachprice, "itmtotal"=> $itmtotal));
    } else {
        // Run if the bill has at least one item in it
        foreach($_SESSION["bill_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while(list($key,$value)=each($each_item)){
                if($key=="itemcode" && $value == $itemcode){
                    // That item is in cart already so push a error message in to screen
                    $wasFound = true;
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var error = "<?= $wasFound ?>";
                    if(error == "true") {
                        alert("You trying to add same item twice")
                    }
                    </script>
                    <?php 
                    }//close if condition
            }//close while loop
        }//close foreach loop
if($wasFound==false){
    array_push($_SESSION["bill_array"],array("date"=> $date, "billnmbr"=> $billnmbr, "itemcode"=> $itemcode, "itemname"=> $itemname, "exdate"=> $exdate, "eachprice"=> $eachprice, "itmtotal"=> $itmtotal));
}
    }
```

and after assigning i'm trying to retrieve those date with these codes

```
<?php 
$cartOutput="";
if(!isset($_SESSION["bill_array"]) || count($_SESSION["bill_array"]) < 1 ) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'> Bill is still empty </hd>";
}
else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["bill_array"]as $each_item ) {
        $i++;
    echo    $cartOutput = "<h2> Bill item $i </h2>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($each_item)){
        $date1=$row["date"];
        $billnmbr1=$row["billnmbr"];
        $itemcode1=$row["itemcode"];
        $itemname1=$row["itemname"];
        $exdate1=$row["exdate"];
        $eachprice1=$row["eachprice"];
        $itmtotal1=$row["itmtotal"];
        }
    }
     echo $date1;
     echo $billnmbr1;
     echo $itemcode1;
     echo $itemname1;
     echo $exdate1;
     echo $eachprice1;
     echo $itmtotal1;
    }



?>
```

i can't figure out where the error is. can anyone help me please

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc need a resourc, not the array you got from session.

Comment: yes that is the thing, but how can i correct this code ?

Comment: i also tried using mysql_fetch_array but it also giving me the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop an array as if it were a database resultset. You actually don't need a loop here, you can just access the values directly, by key.

For example, try this:

```
echo $each_item['date'];
```

Comment: i did this but now it is giving me an error saying...

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in J:\xampp\htdocs\pharmacy\biling.php on line 290
on line 290 i have these code $date1=$row["date"];

Comment: Well, I found an extra `)` on the code I posted (now fixed) but it shouldn't cause *that* error.

Comment: when i echo $row it echoing without any errors but all data in a single string. but i want to take those data separately to variables

Comment: Forget the code I suggested. Please post the output of `var_dump($each_item)` so we can understand the structure of your data.

Comment: Bill item 4
array(7) { ["date"]=> string(8) "05/08/12" ["billnmbr"]=> string(3) "553" ["itemcode"]=> string(5) "0658v" ["itemname"]=> string(9) "vitamin c" ["exdate"]=> string(8) "06/12/14" ["eachprice"]=> string(2) "50" ["itmtotal"]=> string(3) "500" }

Comment: thank you very much...... its working....................... Yahoooooooo!!!!!!!!!!! you ara a god...... wow thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you ........

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$result = array();
foreach($_SESSION["bill_array"] as $row){
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

This way you would get the result in an array.
And actually access those variables using.

> $result[0],$result[1], etc

Comment: using this i can get this 

rray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => a
            [billnmbr] => 
            [itemcode] => 
            [itemname] => 
            [exdate] => 
            [eachprice] => 
            [itmtotal] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => aa
            [billnmbr] => 
            [itemcode] => b
            [itemname] => 
            [exdate] => 
            [eachprice] => 
            [itmtotal] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => c
            [billnmbr] => d
            [itemcode] => e